This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used. in dataScan list FlutterBluePlus
I'm getting an error:

This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used.

on the line: List<ScanResult> res = dataScan;.
I'm currently stuck on this, what do I have to do to fix this error?
Full code:
isLoading.value = true;

FlutterBluePlus
  .startScan(timeout: const Duration(seconds: 4))
  .then((dataScan) async {
    bool printerUdahAda = false;
    int printerIdx = 0;
    
    List<ScanResult> res = dataScan; // error here
    
    for (var data in res) {
      if ("${data.device.id}" == await getDevicePrinter) {
        printerUdahAda = true;
        break;
      } else {
        printerUdahAda = false;
      }
      printerIdx++;
    }


startScan returns a Future which won't have a value for dataScan. I think you have to go back to FlutterBluePlus.scanResults to get a stream of results instead.
